# Doppelanmeldung oder Doppeltanmeldung

Tags: word-choice

Offenbar ist laut [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Doppelanmeldung%2CDoppeltanmeldung&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CDoppelanmeldung%3B%2Cc0) nur Doppelanmeldung üblich. Es klingt dennoch für mich ungewöhnlich. Man ist ja doppelt angemeldet. Der Duden schweigt sich aus. Und dann gibt es *doppeltwirkend* und nicht *doppelwirkend*.

Die Anmeldung zum Doppel ist hier nicht gemeint. Nur die zweifache Anmeldung.

Spricht irgendetwas gegen Doppeltanmeldung?

Comment: Das ist auf den zweiten Blick eine sehr interessante Frage: Ersetzt man "doppel(t)-" durch das Synonym "zweifach", läßt sich die von mic beschriebene Bedeutungsnuance nämlich nicht erreichen.

Answer (score 4):

I think Doppeltanmeldung (-> doppelte Anmeldung) has the connotation of being done by mistake (e.g. one person registers two times at the same place e.g. by pressing a button twice as he first saw no reaction), or of being something unwanted on the side of the party accepting the registrations.

A Doppelanmeldung would be on purpose.

Ich denke, das Wort Doppeltanmeldung (-> doppelte Anmeldung) wird eher verwendet, wenn es sich bei der Anmeldung um einen Fehler handelt (z.B. eine Person registriert sich zweimal, weil sie einen Button ein zweites Mal drückt, weil beim ersten Mal scheinbar nichts passiert) oder die Anmeldestelle derartige Anmeldungen nicht haben möchte.

Eine Doppelanmeldung geschieht dagegen mit Absicht.